# Cooking pasta in the microwave

Tags: pasta, microwave

I have a microwave "pot" that I use for steaming vegetables. The instructions say it can also be used for cooking pasta, which seems sacrilege to me.
Does anybody know if the result would be a good *al dente* pasta if cooked in the microwave?  I'd hate to waste a batch of my home made pasta just to try it.

Comment: Eh. Fresh pasta takes less than 3 minutes to cook in boiling water. Why would you need to microwave this?

Comment: arghhh... as an italian, I'm dying a little on this one :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You know, I'm right there with you on the sacrilege part, but nowadays I microwave pasta all the time. **You need to use a non-starchy pasta for this to work.** I use plain store-bought Barilla Plus because I love it anyway.  For fresh pasta, you could try a small experiment; I've never tried with freshly-made pasta.

It takes less time than boiling on the stove for me because I do this:

1. Fill up the electric kettle with water and turn it on.
2. I use a 1/2 gallon Pyrex measuring cup as my "pot", and I put an inch or so of water in that and pop it in the microwave for four minutes to warm it up.
3. When the water's boiling in the kettle and the oven timer expires, I take out the Pyrex container, add the pasta and a little oil and some salt (optionally a little vinegar), and then pour in the boiling water to cover by an inch or so.
4. Dumpling-like pasta (rotini or penne) take about 8:30 to cook on high (I've got I *think* an 1100 watt oven; experiment); spaghetti 5:30, thin spaghetti 4:30.

I know it sounds like a horrible sin, but I started doing it when I needed to cook small portions of pasta for my kids.  I tried it myself, and realized that I could tell absolutely no difference from the results I got in my big pasta pot. When I need to boil a lot of pasta (like 2 14oz boxes) I still use the big pot of course, but a pound or less actually cooks up perfectly fine. My pasta cooker is enormous and takes a long time to come up to the boil.

Now once I tried this (not thinking clearly, obviously) with some very starchy, fancy pasta, and it did  not work **at all**. But maybe because it's got so much extra protein, Barilla Plus comes out absolutely fine. (It's good for you too.)

*edit* — Here's an update: I still do this, but recently one of the seemingly endless succession of microwave ovens I've had recently died, and I'm pretty sure it's because it somewhat frequently overheated while doing this very thing (cooking pasta). Now I don't blame the technique, really, since an oven should probably be designed with the possibility of hot stuff being inside of them for some periods of time, but be warned. (It overheated probably 10 times or so over the course of a couple years before dying, so it was right about at what I find to be typical end-of-life anyway.)

Comment: Barilla is indeed a very good brand. Some people in Italy prefer Voiello, but I find it takes a little too long to cook properly.

Comment: Ciao @Stefano - I like "plain" blue-box Barilla, but here I refer to the "Barilla Plus", and I don't know if it is sold in Italy. I understand that in Italy you can also buy a "premium" Barilla made with old-style bronze equipment, and I have never seen that in the US.

Comment: Oh also - my *favorite* commercial pasta is Giuseppe Cocco, but that's hard to find here. Also it is a little expensive.

Comment: I believe you this works, but it sounds like too much trouble. I always cook 170 g pasta at once, and do it in a 1.5 l pot on stovetop. It gets to boil quickly, and noodle cooking time is comparable with your microwave numbers. The method needs no kettle, is easy to stir, I can prevent a foamover quickly, nothing crunches a peeking noodle end, and I can constantly take out a piece and test for doneness. So I don't see how the microwave could be more convenient.

Comment: @rumtscho it just depends on the physics of your kitchen I guess :-)

Comment: When my oven died, I also cooked pasta in the microwave, with good success.  Shorter shapes are more convenient, but he quality is the same

Comment: They actually make  two-quart measuring cups?!

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch yes, [Pyrex half-gallon "cups" are available](http://goo.gl/jlGr9J).

Comment: excellent recipe. nice al dente pasta. Trader Joe's rotini, 8:30 in a 1300 watt oven

Comment: Brilliant, just cooked enough pasta for 2 adults in my microwave rice steamer - pint and half of boiling water from the kettle and a little oil and salt. Perfect in 5 mins 1000w microwave. No more steaming up my windows in future this is the way forward. thank you for the tips.

Comment: They even make one gallon Pyrex "cups"... I have one of each (1G, 2Qt).  Very useful for things like steaming broccoli in the microwave.  Not very useful for measuring things if you want precision of any sort ;)

Answer (score 8):

All pasta needs to cook is hot water, it doesn't even have to be plentiful hot water at that. Kenji over at serious eats food lab just did an article about it. (link http://www.seriouseats.com/2010/05/how-to-cook-pasta-salt-water-boiling-tips-the-food-lab.html) As your microwave is very good at heating water it shouldn't be a stretch to cook pasta in it.  I would say that i would try it a few times with some cheap store bought at first because all microwaves vary in terms of wattage and eveness so the amount of time it will take to get the water correct will vary greatly one to the other.

Also you are going to have make sure that there isn't any noodles uncovered as the microwave will turn them crunchy immediately.  You will also have to stir a few times over the course of the cook to make sure that you don't get clumps.

Homemade pasta in particular needs very hot water to start so you will need to bring the water up to temp before adding the pasta.

Comment: hot water _and_ _salt_.

Comment: sorry, and salt is very important, thanks for the catch stefano.

Comment: No prob. It's because I just saw a TV program where Danes cooked for Italians, and they forgot to put the salt, so it's commonly forgot, unless you see it done by your parents for 20 years.

Comment: and a touch of oil helps to cut down foaming

Answer (score 6):

I can't speak for your pot specifically, but I microwave pasta all the time. My reason - I'm just one person and it's simple. I don't have anything fancy - just a plastic Glade (or similar) food storage container. Although I keep meaning to pick up one of the big, glass Pyrex measuring cups to use as my new bowl. That would shorten my cooking time too no doubt.

Either way, here's how I do it: Put in the desired amount, drizzle a tiny bit of oil over the dry pasta, swish it around a little, I use hot tap water, 50% power, 12-14min (depending on the type of pasta), drain, dress, eat.

Why so long?  The 50% power.  I'm sure that if I wanted to perfect a quicker method I could. But the point is - it's simple.  Too many times on higher power it boiled over and I ended up with the sticky pasta-gluey mess in my microwave and down the sides of my container <-- = not simple.  Less power + longer time = less likely to over-cook or boil over.

Answer (score 2):

I microwave pasta often. I sometimes cook it on defrost settings for 10 minutes, mostly at regular settings for between 3 and 5 minutes for one cup of macaroni, say. The trick is not to use too much water; you can always check after a couple of minutes and add more liquid if the pasta seems too dry. I use a 2 quart pyrex or ceramic bowl, and cover tightly with plastic wrap.

Why boil ten cups of water if you only need one? Why wrestle a giant pasta pot to the sink to throw away 9 cups of water when all you have to do is swish the pasta around in one cup?

I often cook the other ingredients along with the pasta, I'm going to mix it together on my plate, anyway.

I cook rice in the micky, too, but there is not much time saved.

Answer (score 0):

They make a microwave pasta cooker called Fasta Pasta and it cooks pasta to perfection.  I love mine!

Comment: If recommending a gadget and naming branded products, it is good form to research commonly available brands and list more than one example.